# Is it possible to have a for loop run through multiple arrays/variables in C programming?

Tags: c, arrays, logic

I have a program that takes 20 samples from 25 people and then has to associate each number in that sample with a percentage.

is there a way to,through a function, create a for loop that will run through all of the samples without me manually doing it?

ex.

```
int sample1[20]={1,2...20};
...
int sample25[20]={1,7..97};
```

I have a for loop going through one of the arrays and associating it with a larger array of 500 numbers. I need to know if there is a way to run through sample1 then 2, then 3, etc.. without me manually going into the function and putting a new array in.

Or can you send an array to a function?

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int x;
float valid,mean,total=0;


for (x = 0;x < 20; x++)
{
    float percent[500]={4.268,  4.014,  3.905,  3.853,  3.765,  3.949,  3.832..etc};
    int sample1[20]={66,20,221,321,...};


    sample1[x];
    valid=percent[sample1[x]-1];

    printf("\n%d = %.3f",sample1[x],percent[sample1[x]-1]);

    total= total+ percent[sample1[x]-1];
}
    mean= total/20;
    printf("\n\nThe mean percentage for the sample is %.3f",mean);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, there is. By creating a new array (or vector) of arrays. This is exactly what containers are for, don't create multiple variables like this.

Comment: Template magic could be used here but I do not think you will be satisfied :)

Comment: Easily, if I only knew the logic behind... For example, why are `sample25[1] == 7` and `sample25[19] == 97`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a two-dimentsional array, i.e. `int sample[25][20]`, and use two nested `for` to process the whole. You certainly can pass such an array to a function. Check out a good C tutorial, like the [ones by Steve Summit](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/cclass.html). Yes, they are quite old, but still relevant. A more modern approach is [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c-tutorial.html).

Comment: Cool. But I have to calculate a mean average percent after each sample. How could i incorporate that.

Like after each sample, or array[20] ,calculate and display mean

Comment: Do it just like you'd do it for a single, say, `sample15[]`

Comment: I posted my code up top. Maybe itll make more sense on what im trying to do

Answer (score 1):

Seems pretty straight forward unless I'm missing the point (altogether possible). How about:

```
for(int i = 0; i < people; i++)
{
    // Set person to work on
    for(int j = 0; j < sample; j++)
    {
        //process numbers
    }
}
```

Or you can shift the loops to have the outside be samples and the inside be people.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with posters saying this can be handled with a single array. Pardon the random data generation bits:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DATA_SIZE  500
#define NUM_PEOPLE  25
#define NUM_SAMPLES 20

float random_samples[DATA_SIZE] = {};

void create_random_samples();
float calculate_average( float *arr, int size );
float random_i_to_j( float i, float j );

int main()
{
    float sample_average[NUM_SAMPLES] = {};

    int i, j;
    for ( i = 0; i < NUM_PEOPLE; i++ ) {
        for ( j = 0; j < NUM_SAMPLES; j++ ) {
            create_random_samples();
            sample_average[j] = calculate_average( random_samples, DATA_SIZE );
        }
    }

    for ( i = 0; i < NUM_PEOPLE; i++ ) {
        for ( j = 0; j < NUM_SAMPLES; j++ ) {
           printf( " person: %d sample: %d sample average: %.2f \n", i, j, sample_average[j] );
        }
    }
    return 0;  
}

void create_random_samples( int num )
{
    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < DATA_SIZE; i++ ) {
        random_samples[i] = random_n_to_m( 2.00, 5.00 );  // random samples between 2.00 and 5.00
    }
}

float calculate_average( float *arr, int size )
{
    float average = 0;
    float total = 0;
    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
        total += arr[i];
    }
    average = total / size;
    return average;
}

float random_i_to_j( float i, float j )
{
    return i + ( rand() / ( RAND_MAX / ( j - i )));
}
```